# How to apply time-window related data analysis via Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume there're two dataframes, recording two different operations (who at which time did the operation) respectively.

```
# operation A
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 138], ['a', 140], ['b', 150]], columns=['name', 'timestamp'])
print df1

# operation B
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 145], ['b', 170]], columns=['name', 'timestamp'])
print df2

--output--
  name  timestamp
0    a        138
1    a        140
2    b        150
  name  timestamp
0    a        145
1    b        170
```

What I intend to do is to retrieve consecutive operations A->B where B happens within 10 units against previous A happening time.

In the example above, (B, a, 145) and (A, a, 140) will be a qualified consecutive operations, yet (B, b, 170) and (A, b, 150) will not be since 170-150=20>10 units.

Could anyone give me the most efficient way to processing this model is the data is relatively large (10,000-100,000)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would create a new column that is the difference between consecutive timestamps

```
df1.loc[:, 'time_diff'] = df1.timestamp.diff()
df1
  name  timestamp  time_diff
0    a        138        NaN
1    a        140          2
2    b        150         10

df2.loc[:, 'time_diff'] = df2.timestamp.diff()
```

then you want to see when `name` transitions. you can do this using `duplicated`. You also want to ignore the first row (so when time_diff is null). This will tell you the rows where a transition happened, and you can examine the time_diff column however you want

```
df1.loc[~df1.name.duplicated() & df1.time_diff.notnull(),:]
df1
  name  timestamp  time_diff
2    b        150         10
```

vs.

```
df2.loc[~df2.name.duplicated() & df2.time_diff.notnull(),:]
df2
  name  timestamp  time_diff
1    b        170         25
```

so if you have tons of rows, you can have some logic like

```
df.loc[~df.name.duplicated() & df.time_diff.notnull() & (df.time_diff <= 10)]
```

Comment: My problem is not comparing the time in a single df (one operation), but to compare it between different dataframes. Could you see my example more thoroughly? You could try the code to see whether the result is the same as expected.  Great thanks!

Comment: you would still have to do all of the above. you could finalize with taking the shape of my last line of code. if shape > 0, then that df falls under your criteria. you would have to iterate through all of your dfs

Comment: I think I get what u means, Thanks bro~